# Automated Process User in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

We are trying to automated some of the data maskign activities as part of our post sandbox refresh activity. We have achieved this by implementing sandboxpostcopy interface. I found out that the apex class when refreshing the sandbox is executed via automated process user. My question is that will Automated Process user will fire triggers, WFR, Duplicate RUles, Validation rules etc ?

Answer (score 1):

The Automated Process User has limited authorizations (as pointed out in many articles online, e.g. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mysterious-automated-process-user-salesforce-bill-wu/ and https://unofficialsf.com/pauple_helpie/the-autoproc-user-scheduling-flows-triggering-flows-permissions/) but it **does** trigger all other automation like apex triggers, workflow rules, duplicate rules, validations rules, record-triggered flows etc etc.

Comment: Does that means that all the triggers WFR, Validation rules will get fired if the run method of the sandboxPostCOpy interface is responsible of masking data on couple of objects ?

Comment: I would expect so, indeed. I've seen validation rules run on this process.

Comment: Thank you Claribois. The reason i am asking this question is because i saw the comment on this idea that automated process user does not invoke triggers or WFR or Validation rules. Hence, trying to confirm..

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZq1UAF/process-builders-triggers-on-insert-or-update-by-automated-process-user

Comment: From my own experience I can definitely confirm that apex triggers and workflow rules run if you use Scheduled Flow to create new records. The child records created by the apex trigger have the 'Automated Process' user as their CreatedBy user. The record history shows 'Automated Process' as the User that did the field changes which are done as part of workflow rule field updates.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up Alex. I actually see a User named 'Automated Process' in my field history doing updates (in July 2022) that are triggered by a workflow rule. And those records are created by a Scheduled Flow (which has API version 49) and Automated Process user is also marked as the record creator. So I'm not sure what to believe now..

Comment: I put together a new summary of all the vetted information I could unearth about Automated Process User and Default Workflow User (https://unofficialsf.com/understanding-the-automated-process-user-the-default-workflow-user/)

Comment: @AlexEdelstein that's awesome! I'll go through it and let you know if I have any comments or things to add.

Answer (score -1):

I confirmed from Salesforce that the automated process does not run any of the backend functionality that inclides triggers, WFR, VR, Flows, etc. It by passes all that. Hopefully this would help someone else looking for the answer

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I've just verified with the Salesforce Flow development team that Automated Process User will execute triggers and other automation. Can you provide any additional detail on what you heard?

Comment: Ok. I have escalated the case to the higher support personnel. Let’s see what they are going to say. 
Also, I was able to find the automated user Id that I can use to make sure that the triggers and WFR are not ran if the record is updated via the automated user